# Where is the Image grabbed with Sample Grab Pylon Basler?

Tags: basler

i'm working on a camera of Basler AG with the pylon sdk. I installed the SDK and run the Sample Code "Grab", which works, but i dont get any Image shown of the camera. Where is the Image stored? Do I need to do anything? In the Pylon Doc there is shown a Image.

Its the C++ Sample of Grab.
Can someone answer me, how i can retrieve the image?

Answer (score 0):

I have some experience with this camera.There are some tips.

1.First step :You should make sure you `open()` camera.

2.Second step:use`StartGrabbing`or `GrabOne`to let camera strat grabbing image,then make sure camera.IsGrabbing(),use  `while (camera.IsGrabbing())`

3.Thrid step:if camera.IsGrabbing()==true,use`camera.RetrieveResult( 5000, ptrGrabResult, TimeoutHandling_ThrowException );`,ptrGrabResult is where image and all data stored.

4.Fourth step: `if (ptrGrabResult->GrabSucceeded()==ture)`,use `const uint8_t* pImageBuffer = (uint8_t*) ptrGrabResult->GetBuffer();`to get the image buffer,that's all.

If you can show more detail about your code,it will be more easy to help you figure out a solution.

Answer (score 0):

`Grab` sample does not provide any image display, it's only intended for commandline based camera operation. Use `GUI_ImageWindow` or `GUI_Sample` project instead. These samples use pylon's built-in helper class `CPylonImageWindow` to show images.

Images are cotained in `ptrGrabResult` variable.